# StoredProcedureQuery with output Record Table

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

currently doing stored procedure with output parameter record table.
got a trouble on accessing it on the spring-jpa.

already tried the ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR and ParameterMode.OUT, got confused on what parameter mode should i put for it to display result list.

I got this error below

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined!
```

Oracle stored procedure

```sql
procedure fetch_fund_values(
policy_num in varchar2,
fund_detail out table_fund_policy
);

TYPE record_fund_policy IS RECORD(
policy_num             VARCHAR2
,fund_id             VARCHAR2
,fund_price           NUMBER
);

TYPE table_fund_policy IS TABLE OF record_fund_policy;
```

spring jpa accessing the stored procedure

```java
try {
    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = this.entityManager
            .createStoredProcedureQuery("fetch_fund_values")
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("policy_num", String.class,
                    ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("table_fund_policy",
                    void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
            .setParameter("policy_num", policyNumber);

    return storedProcedure.getResultList();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    throw ex;
}
```

I'm currently looking on the way that i can access the result list.
Should i create a return POJO?

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking, the Types should be on the DB level and not on the package.
For it to be discovered by the JDBC.

I switch on the JDBC since its more powerful accessing storedProcedures.